# How to remove the only the Themes options from the Apprerance menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to **only** remove the Themes option from the Appearance menu in the WordPress dashboard. The option I want removed is marked in red.

[image]

I have tried,

```
remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
```

But it removed the Appearance menu completely.

I found another function to remove the sub menu but unsure what the second option has to be since both Appearance and Themes are linked to wp-admin/themes.php

```
remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', '')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it. Add to functions file:

```
function remove_menus(){  
remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php');
}  
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```